# Report more than 200 lines cut/pasted -- Vividly?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register, paste, message

I have a text document where I frequently move/cut large blocks of text.

Every 2-3 months I inadvertently cut or paste a huge number of lines (60,000 today) and discover the error hours, or even days, later, after having made several edits after the cut/paste error.

Correcting the document is a trial.  The document is so big (15 MB) that gvim diff takes minutes to jump from one block to another.

So, I'd like Vim to detect and report cut/paste events > 200 lines, so that I can catch these errors immediately.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have report parameter disabled? Check it with `:set report?` and set the floor value, e.g. 5 (the default is 2) with `:set report=5` So, when you do a `200dd` or `d200d` (or any valid combinations) by accident, you should see in the status line: 200 fewer line
Also set commands display with `:set showcmd` to show your (partial) commands in status line (this option requires the `+cmdline_info` feature). With that you'd see you were deleting.

Update from comments. All above is already in place, the OP was seeking for a way to have a persistent message (`showcmd` and `report` may be missed when one is focused elsewhere on the text). The option to check then is `statusline` string (empty by default) where one can use:

- `%m` to show terse `[+]` when buffer is modified, or `[-]` when *modifiable* is off
- `%M` to show, instead, terse `,+` or `,-` (in your script call `getbufvar(bufnr('%'),'&mod')` for that information as boolean)
- `%L` to show the number of lines in the buffer (in your script call `line('$')` for that information as integer)
- `%p` to show the percent of the buffer in lines displayed
- `%#`HlGrp`#` to set the highlight group named *HlGrp* (for example `%#WarningColor#` or `%#ErrorColor#` in that case)
- `%{`expr`}` to evaluate the *expr* within the curly braces (expression that cannot contain `}` of course, and may be a function call) and substitute the result
- `{%`expr`%}` for the same purpose, but the result is evaluated again to proceed `%`flags inside,
- and much more. [`:h 'stl`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#E540)

I don't have a good and definitive answer, but sure you have to write your custom function and call it in the status line. You may also check well known plugins like [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) and [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) that come batteries included and customisation.

Comment: Not disabled, and I have seen that report.

The (my) problem is that I don't observe that default report, because I'm so focused on the text, and editing so quickly.

To be more clear in my question, I'm looking for a very visible report -- ALL-CAPS, red font, and persistence on the screen until I hit a key to close the report.

Comment: Oh, I see, you need `statusline` option then. This one isn't easy to set up (imho) but once done it works like a charm. There's an indicator for buffer modified (one of the terse `[+]`, `[-]`, `,+`, `,-`) but you can define and call your own function for a better message. That remain on the screen until you save the buffer or force close it.

Comment: For colours, I know nothing about how to add them in the status (so you can have indication in red for example.) Some plugins can do it and are very customisable (they do more with the status line and can shine a lot), so maybe you can check them too. [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) (need Python interpreter and also that your Vim is compiled with the binding) and [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) are the two most-and-well known.

Comment: 5 years ago I released yet another statusline plugin, streamline.vim !, but I have not looked at VimL since then -- forgotten, for now; I was hoping vim had something more direct for this requirement, perhaps via the relatively new popup window feature.  For a status line route, I suppose there's a line_count() func that accepts a register ?

Comment: [KaraMCC/vim-streamline](https://github.com/KaraMCC/vim-streamline)? Reading the source, I can see it sets the `statusline` and uses `%#ErrorColor#` (kinda red) and `%#WarningColor#` (kinda orange/darkyellow) :) The number of lines in the buffer is given by `line('$')` function. The number of lines in a selection is `line("'>") - line("'<") + 1` (to try in Ex-cmd-line, put `:echo ` in front, it shall return the same result as `:'<,'>s/^//n` or [<kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-g</kbd>](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#v_g_CTRL-G) directly) So I guess there's a way to do same for a reg

Comment: Sounds like a viable base.  My streamline.vim has fixed color, the one you found is from 2yrs later.
Thanks for your help !

https://github.com/cesheridan/streamline.vim#readme.  Keeping the post open a little while longer to see if there's something readier-to-go

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the autocommand events `TextChanged` and `TextYankPost`; you might be able to check the number of changed lines. For the former I'm not 100% sure how you would do that; in the latter case, which is only for yanks and deletes that do not go to the `_` register, you can use `v:event.regcontents`.

Once you determine that you want to show a message, consider `popup_notification()` as a starting point.